# Como puedo sumar desde un textbox a un campo de tabla en php?

Tags: php, html

Tengo mi columna "NumVentas" en mi tabla, y necesito que se le sume lo que le agregue en un textbox, o de ser posible que al presionar el botón enviar automáticamente sume +1 en ese campo.

Comment: Muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. Como verás, el código en los comentarios es ilegible.